# Inserting Formula into Conditional Formatting Function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I am trying to conditional format the **Paired-up Table** according to the result of the **Paired** column.

The **"BoyA"** column reflects the Row number of the **Paired-up Table**, the **"BoyB"** column reflects the column number of the **Paired-up Table**.

For example: If the value in the **Paired** column is 1, I would like to highlight the cell in the **Paired-up** Table according to the BoyA and BoyB.

Since the **Paired** column shows the value of 1 when BoyA=1 and BoyB=5, I have to highlight the value 2 from Row 1 and Column 5 of the **Paired-up** Table, so on and so forth.[image: Final Result]

I have tried many different ways by tying the formula into the conditional formatting function of excel, but in vain. Thank you!

[Final Result Should show this]

Comment: How do you build the Paired-up table? If with INDEX-MATCH than you can use the same logic for the format condition - returning the value for "paired" instead of "score" - than if equals to 1 = true

Comment: Do the row and column numbers 1-8 actually appear along the side and top of your paired-up table? If so, it makes answering the question a bit easier.

Comment: Hi lke. I built the paired-up table by directly typing in the number. I got the result of the "Score" column by using the INDEX function.

Comment: Hi Tom.
Do the row and column numbers 1-8 actually appear along the side and top of your paired-up table? - Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Since there can be only one combination of BoyA and BoyB for each score/pair, you can use a SUMIFS formula to easily find the match you are looking for (both to report the score data and to highlights the paired ones). A formula like this should do the trick:

=SUMIFS( *Paired_Column* , *BoyA_Column* , *Ordinate_Value* , *BoyB_Column* , *Abscissa_Value* )

Assuming a situation like this:
[image]

the formula you are looking for should be like this:

=SUMIFS($N:$N,$K:$K,$A3,$L:$L,B$2)